# how use highlight code block in markdown list

Tags: markdown, jekyll, highlight, nested-lists

Hi guys I have one problem.
I use markdown in jekyll. and using nested lists

### I wrote that

1. list...
2. .....
3. list 3

   - 3-1

     > {% highlight xml %}
     >   
     >   commandline
     >   -registryMultiLanguage -GAON -forceSystemInitialize -defaultDB MySQL -nl ko 
     >   
     >   {% endhighlight %}
   - 3-2 text... (IMG ...)
4. Tadpole API Server 전반적인 속도와 기능 향상이 있었습니다.

   - 쿼리 내에 Apache Velocity 를 적용할 수 있도록 했습니다.  즉, if else를 쓸 수 있도록 했습니다.
   - 올챙이 본체에서 API 관리 창을 새롭게 만들었고, 테스트할 수 있도록 개선했습니다.

---

But last list item(4) and 3-2 item, make NEW LIST. WHY??? see that

---

1. list...
2. .....
3. list 3

   - 3-1

     > {% highlight xml %}
     >   
     >   commandline
     >   -registryMultiLanguage -GAON -forceSystemInitialize -defaultDB MySQL -nl ko 
     >   
     >   {% endhighlight %}

*text... (IMG ...)

1 . Tadpole API Server 전반적인 속도와 기능 향상이 있었습니다.
   * 쿼리 내에 Apache Velocity 를 적용할 수 있도록 했습니다.  즉, if else를 쓸 수 있도록 했습니다. 
   * 올챙이 본체에서 API 관리 창을 새롭게 만들었고, 테스트할 수 있도록 개선했습니다.

---

``` and ~~~ is didn work my system

if you want github repo, see here https://github.com/jungheelee/TadpoleForDBTools/blame/gh-pages/_posts/2015-09-20-v1.6.4.markdown

publish page is here
http://jungheelee.github.io/TadpoleForDBTools/release/2015/09/20/v1.6.4.html

How insert code block in list? plz answer to me

Comment: This question is a bit unclear to me. Would you mind trying to format it correctly and describing your problem more precisely. You can do so by clicking on edit below your question. Also, please take a few minutes to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I read that page. but I'm not English very well sorry T_T

Answer (score 0):

Code blocks are indicated by indenting them by 4 spaces. Block level items are nested in a list by indenting them 4 spaces. Therefore, when you want to nest a code block in a list, you must indent it twice; once to nest it in a list, and a second time to indicate it is a code block. It you are nesting a code block in a multi-level nested list, then you must indent the code block four spaces for each level of the nested list and one more time to indicate it is a code block.

Looking at the source page you linked to, it appears that you have two levels of nesting in the list, plus the code block. That requires three levels of indentation for each line of the code block, or 12 spaces. Also, the code block should always have a blank line before it and a blank line after it.

```
6. 전반적인 한글화 작업을 했습니다. (한국 사용자는 꼭 한글을 쓰세요.)
   * 영문 윈도우를 사용하는 Tomcat 사용자는 `web.xml`을 수정하세요. 아래처럼 `-nl ko`를 넣으시면 됩니다.

            {% highlight xml %}
            <init-param>
                <param-name>commandline</param-name>
                <param-value>-registryMultiLanguage -GAON -forceSystemInitialize -defaultDB MySQL -nl ko <!-- nl en -debuglog -console --></param-value>
            <init-param>
            {% endhighlight %}

   * 독립 실행 모듈을 사용 중 이시면 tadpole-standalone.ini 파일에 `-nl ko`를 추가하세요.
![독립 실행 모듈 한글 설정](https://tadpoledbhub.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/22773763/%E1%84%89%E1%85%B3%E1%84%8F%E1%85%B3%E1%84%85%E1%85%B5%E1%86%AB%E1%84%89%E1%85%A3%E1%86%BA%202015-09-20%20%E1%84%8B%E1%85%A9%E1%84%92%E1%85%AE%2012.59.38.png?version=1&modificationDate=1442721601991&api=v2)
```